# Subtract days from timestamp python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time

I am calculating end timestamp and then I have to subtract days (example days = 10) from the timestamp and then convert it to get the start timestamp.
Calculating start_timestamp and end_timestamp like this:

```
import datetime

end_timestamp = time.time()
end_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(end_timestamp)

start_date = end_time.date() - datetime.timedelta(days=10)
start_timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(start_date) + " " + str(end_time.time()), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').timestamp())
```

I need both the start and end in timestamp format only.
What is the best pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Just subtract days from `end_timestamp` only. `start_timestamp = end_timestamp - datetime.timedelta(days=10)`

Comment: @techytushar I have changed the question (code part) please take a look. I want both timestamp earlier it was giving datetime format.

Answer (score 2):

what about something like

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

t1 = datetime.now(timezone.utc) # end time
t0 = t1 - timedelta(10)         # start time

# if you need UNIX time:
start_ts, end_ts = t0.timestamp(), t1.timestamp()
print(start_ts, end_ts)
# 1608972059.652785 1609836059.652785

# if needed you can combine date and time from different datetime objects:
dt = datetime.combine(t0.date(), t1.time()).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
print(dt.isoformat())
# 2020-12-26T08:40:59.652785+00:00
```

I'm explicitly setting the time zone to UTC to avoid any hickups due to Python treating naive datetime as local time while UNIX time refers to a UTC date/time<sup>1</sup>.

If you work with UNIX time in seconds since the epoch, you could also add/subtract days directly as multiples of the seconds in a day (86400):

```
import time

t1 = time.time()
t0 = t1 - 86400*10

dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(t0, tz=timezone.utc)
print(dt.isoformat())
# 2020-12-26T08:51:07.015367+00:00
```

---

<sup>1 <sub>However, note that UNIX time does not include leap seconds.</sub></sup>